# Adding constraint to supertable with child instances in an Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, constraints

I've got a hierarchy pretty similar to this one in an Oracle Database

```
CREATE TYPE PersonUdt AS OBJECT(
    personId number(10),
    Name varchar(20)
)INSTANTIABLE NOT FINAL;


CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE PatientUdt under PersonUdt(
    insurancePlan varchar(100)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE DoctorUdt under PersonUdt(
    area varchar(20)
);

CREATE TABLE Person of PersonUdt(
    personId PRIMARY KEY
)OBJECT IDENTIFIER IS SYSTEM GENERATED;
```

I've got some insertions on the table,like

```
INSERT INTO person VALUES(DoctorUdt(1, 'Alfred', 'Area One'));
```

I would like to create a constraint to limit the area in which the a doctor can work. Let's say, limit it to Area one, two and three.

Is it possible to do this using `ALTER TABLE x ADD CONSTRAINT...` functions?

Thanks in advance!